# QTP: How to handle a pop up window that shows up at an uncertain time

Tags: testing, automation, qtp

I encounter a situation that the scripts would be run for hundreds of times, and I have tried twice, the script would be terminated by unexpected pop up window (window from program that pre-installed from my company, and there are several candidate programs that will lead to the problem). It would be very annoying because I have to stay in company very late to get the pop up window.

What is the solution when you come across this kind of problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cases where you want to recover a test run from a semi-expected situation QTP supplies [Recovery Scenarios](http://www.learnqtp.com/recovery-scenarios-in-qtp/).

Comment: Thanks Motti, yeah Recovery Scenarios will help fix the problem.